# Alternative to Exchangepop3

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

we have exhange server and we really like eXchangePOP3? But I find it expensive. Is there an alternative to exchangepop3 with similiar functionality.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a server, Windows, Exchange and all the various CALs, and you think a couple of hundred dollars is expensive?!!

Answer (score 2):

[My answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/96190/recommendations-for-a-pop3-connector-for-exchange-2007/96399#96399) re: using the open-source fetchmail program might help you, though the value of your time should come into play in your thought-process.

Comment: I second the point about the value of someone's time. I've seen lots of people spend $300 worth of their time in order to "save" the cost of a $100 licence for something.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a linux/freebsd box and run fetchmail + postfix and some web interface to have users subscribe to their webmail account.

You could also use [fetchmail](http://unixmail-w32.sourceforge.net/) under windows.  Never tried using it, so can't speak to how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/). This is a proxy that connects to Exchange via Outlook Web Access, and serves it up as a normal POP3 protocol (or calDav) and even has access to the global address book. I've used it with Thunderbird (+ Lightning) to access the corporate Exchange instead of Outlook.

You can run it per-user or in a server configuration where 1 DavMail proxy serves for all users.

Its open source, so free.